# Add Variable to ID with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is hiding a div with a certain ID, when it is called.

```
$('#starrating').hide();
```

This works fine but when I try adding a variable to it, it does not work.

I am trying to do it this way and it is not working:

```
$('#starrating'[imageid]).hide();
```

I need to know how you would add a variable unto the ID. If I add the number instead of the variable it works fine:

```
$('#starrating234343').hide();
```

Comment: Use string concatenation.`$('#starrating'+imageid).hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say `+` to concatenate:

```
$('#starrating'+imageid).hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `imageid` is a string or a number, you have to append using `+` operator

```
$('#starrating' + imageid).hide();
```